# Android: I need a button that kills anything played by the MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I have an app that plays several different audio files on a loop, via several different buttons. I want to program a single button that will stop the MediaPlayer, regardless of what audio file is currently being played. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Call `stop()` on your `MediaPlayer` object to stop the playback of whatever the `MediaPlayer` is playing.